# How can I update the state of my vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, store

I'm new here so please forgive me if my write isn't good or the code section... still trying to figure it out.

so I've been trying a lot of forms in order to achieve the result that I want to but with no success...

Basically the app is getting a salary (amount) and there is the total sum in the account (currentSalar) both of them are from type string and not number... I need to find a way to rest the salary from the total sum and obviously update it.

Here are some screenshots If anyone could help me please.

````````````````````````
   **/index.js** 

import  mutations  from './mutations.js';
import actions from './actions.js';
import getters from './getters.js';

export default {
    namespaced: true, 

    state() {
        return {
            registers: [
                {
                    id: 'user1',
                    currentSalar: '4,400' ,
                    saves: '12,000',
                    currency: '₪',
                    expense: [{salary: '3,000', category: 'Bar:'}]
                },
                {
                    id: 'user2',
                    currentSalar: '100,000',
                    saves: '3,000,000',
                    currency: '$',
                    expense: []
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}

``````````````````````

``````````````````````
**/mutations.js**

export default {
  addRegister(state, payload) {
    const registerToUpdate = state.registers.find(
      (register) => register.id === payload.id
    );

    const expenses = registerToUpdate.expense;  //////* find((expense) => expense.salary === payload.salary) */
    const salary = +expenses.salary;
    let current = +registerToUpdate.currentSalar;

    const newCurrnt = current -= salary;   // should calculate a new value (UPDATE) for the currentSalar by resting the salary
    console.log(newCurrnt);

    expenses.unshift(payload);
  },
};
```````````````````
**/actions.js**

export default {
    addRegister(context, data) {
        const RegisterData = {
            id: context.rootGetters.userId,
            category: data.category,
            salary: data.salary
        }

        context.commit('addRegister', RegisterData);
    }
}

```````````````````````
**/component**

<template>
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Add expense</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="ReturnCat">
      <section>
        <label for="salary">Amount: </label>
        <input type="number" id="salary" v-model.number="salary"/>
      </section>
      <section>
        <label for="category">Category: </label>
        <select id="category" v-model.trim="category">
          <option value="Bar: " id="bar">
            Bar & Restaurants
          </option>
          <option value="Shopping: " id="shopping">Shopping</option>
          <option value="Needs: " id="needs">Needs</option>
        </select>
      </section>
      <base-button class="btn">ADD</base-button>
      <h4><a href="">Add entery insted</a></h4>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      salary: null,
      category: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    expensePath() {
      return this.$router.replace("/register/" + this.id);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    ReturnCat() {
      const form = {
        salary: this.salary,
        category: this.category
      }
      this.$store.dispatch('register/addRegister', form);
      console.log(this.salary, this.category);
    },

  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#salary {
  margin: 1rem auto auto 1rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 11rem;
}
select,
option {
  margin: 1rem auto 2rem 1rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 11rem;
}
.btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 11rem;
}
</style>
`
````````````````````````

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: done! I houpfully did it right... sorry I'm new to all of this

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't understand numbers as strings.

When you want to do arithmetic operations (as I guess you do, since you're developing an app having to do with accounting), you must work with numbers:

```js
  registers: [
    {
      id: "user1",
      currentSalar: 4400,
      saves: 12000,
      currency: "₪",
      expense: [{ salary: 3000, category: "Bar:" }],
    },
    {
      id: "user2",
      currentSalar: 100000,
      saves: 3000000,
      currency: "$",
      expense: []
    }
  ]
```

Even when you're getting this data from a poorly written API which returns numbers as strings, the **first thing** you want to do is to turn them into numbers, before placing them in the store.

And when you try to cast a string to number (by appending `+` to it), if the string contains thousand separators as commas (or anything that's not a digit, a dot, or a scientific number notation - e.g: `'-3e6'`), you're going to get back [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

See it here:

```js
const num = '1,000,000'

console.log( +num ) // NaN

// strip commas from it:
console.log( +num.replaceAll(',', '') ) // 1000000
```

---

And when you want to display the numbers used in the store to the user, if you want to put thousand and decimal separators on them, use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

Comment: thank you very much, in the mutation I need to loop throw all salary right?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You need to improve the question by replacing *"to achieve the result that I want"* with what you actually want. You show us a store and a component that's supposed to add registers to that store. We don't know how you want to display those registers. Nor do we know how you're going to add multiple expenses to the `expense` array in the new register. But no matter what you try, it won't work if you use strings with thousands separators.

Comment: Is the form supposed to add expenses to a particular register? If so, how does the app which register it should add the expense to? Also, if there is any computed data about this register, you should use a computed to get it, instead of updating some prop on the object each time an expense is added or removed. A computed always updates based on its formula. You don't need to save the calculation on the object.

Comment: Basically on the state of the store there is the `expense` that every time someone adds one it's create another object in there with `salary` and `category`, I'm trying to get the `salary` from the mutations so I can rest from the total in the account(`currentSalar`) this new `salary` that the user just add. if you have any suggestions for achieve this result It will be great

Answer (score -1):

solved:)

here is the code:

```js
// index.js
import  mutations  from './mutations.js';
import actions from './actions.js';
import getters from './getters.js';

export default {
    namespaced: true, 

    state() {
        return {
            registers: [
                {
                    id: 'user1',
                    currentSalar: 4400 ,
                    saves: 12000 ,
                    currency: '₪',
                    expense: []
                },
                {
                    id: 'user2',
                    currentSalar: 100000,
                    saves: 3000000,
                    currency: '$',
                    expense: []
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}`

`
// mutations.js

export default {
  addRegister(state, payload) {
    const registerToUpdate = state.registers.find(
      (register) => register.id === payload.id
    );
    
    let current = registerToUpdate.currentSalar;
    const expenses = registerToUpdate.expense;

    current -= payload.salary;
   
    expenses.unshift(payload);
    registerToUpdate.currentSalar =  registerToUpdate.currentSalar - 
payload.salary;
  },
};
```